# Multi Level JSON Data into SQL Using Python

Tags: python, sql, json, sql-server

I've been working on taking JSON data and dumping it into a SQL database. I've run across some data that is "multi level" and I'm stuck on finding the best approach to handle the data and create the correct table structure in SQL.

Here's the portion of the JSON data that has a multi level structure:

```
"LimitedTaxonomy": {
            "Children": [
                {
                    "Children": [
                        {
                            "Children": [],
                            "NewPartCount": 0,
                            "Parameter": "Categories",
                            "ParameterId": -8,
                            "PartCount": 1,
                            "Value": "Logic - Flip Flops",
                            "ValueId": "706"
                        }
                    ],
                    "NewPartCount": 0,
                    "Parameter": "Categories",
                    "ParameterId": -8,
                    "PartCount": 1,
                    "Value": "Integrated Circuits (ICs)",
                    "ValueId": "32"
                }
            ],
            "NewPartCount": 0,
            "Parameter": "Categories",
            "ParameterId": -8,
            "PartCount": 1,
            "Value": "Out of Bounds",
            "ValueId": "0"
        }
```

I have a function that I call when I'm parsing the JSON data that takes the structure and puts data in the SQL tables. Using the JSON data above I'd be passing:

```
thetable = 'LimitedTaxonomy'
the value = {'Children': [{'Children': [{'Children': [], 'NewPartCount': 0, 'Parameter': 'Categories', 'ParameterId': -8, 'PartCount': 1, 'Value': 'Logic - Flip Flops', 'ValueId': '706'}], 'NewPartCount': 0, 'Parameter': 'Categories', 'ParameterId': -8, 'PartCount': 1, 'Value': 'Integrated Circuits (ICs)', 'ValueId': '32'}], 'NewPartCount': 0, 'Parameter': 'Categories', 'ParameterId': -8, 'PartCount': 1, 'Value': 'Out of Bounds', 'ValueId': '0'}
```

```
def create_sql(thetable, thevalue):
    if len(thevalue) > 0:
        #print(thevalue[0], len(thevalue))
        if type(thevalue) is list:
            x = tuple(thevalue[0])
        elif type(thevalue) is dict:
            x = tuple(thevalue)

        a = str(x).replace("'","").replace("(","")

        query = "INSERT INTO " + thetable + " (PartDetailsId, " + a + " VALUES(" + str(data['PartDetails']['PartId'])

        b = ""
        for i in range(len(x)):
            b += ", ?" # I've also seen %s used as a placeholder
        b += ")"
        query += b

        print(query)
        print(thevalue)
        print()

        #TODO Need to check before entering data, list has many records, dict has 1
        if type(thevalue) is list:
            cursor.executemany(query, [tuple(d.values()) for d in thevalue])
        elif type(thevalue) is dict:
            cursor.execute(query, tuple(thevalue.values()))
        cursor.commit()
```

The above function seems to work well with "single level" JSON but this data has basically a table/array (Children) as a column.

In SQL I have the 2 tables as defined like this, which might not be the way to handle this:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [LimitedTaxonomyId]
      ,[PartDetailsId]
      ,[NewPartCount]
      ,[Parameter]
      ,[ParameterId]
      ,[PartCount]
      ,[Value]
      ,[ValueId]
  FROM [Components].[dbo].[LimitedTaxonomy]

SELECT TOP (1000) [ChildrenId]
      ,[LimitedTaxonomyId]
      ,[NewPartCount]
      ,[Parameter]
      ,[ParameterId]
      ,[PartCount]
      ,[Value]
      ,[ValueId]
  FROM [Components].[dbo].[Children]
```

I think I need to check `thevalue` and if contains a list I need to first pull that list out of `thevalue` and then feed remaining data into my `create_sql` function. After that I then put that extracted list back through the `create_sql` function but first querying the SQL Database to grab the `[LimitedTaxonomyId]` value that was just entered.

This sounds like a big mess and maybe it's the only way but I'd like some 2nd opinions on how I'm going about this and if there's perhaps a better way.

Comment: Careful, you're code is *very* open to injection. I **strongly** suggest you look into learning how to parametrise your statements first.

Comment: Yes, this is just for internal testing and use so it really has no safety nets (yet)

Comment: *"this is just for internal testing"* that isn't, and is never, an excuse for writing code with huge security flaws. Write your code right the first time; then you never have to go back and rewrite it, or "accidentality" introduce a catastrophic security flaw in your production environment.

Comment: There is an article about storing hierarchical data in the SQL Server documentation, this should help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Larnu You're correct, no argument there so I'll look into improving it. I'm at the stage now where I just wanted to see if I could get it to work. Are you referring to how I create the query statement and then just execute it?